# Is crossfilter instance mutable or immutable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, crossfilter

I'm a newbie in js...now I'm facing the issue with `crossfilter`.

Say I create a `crossfilter` instance using:

```
var instance = crossfilter(data);
```

I could get a javascript array with:

```
var dataArray = instance.top(Infinity);
```

So my question is: is the `dataArray` I get here mutable or immutable? Since I tried to modify one of the elements and ended up with failure.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript arrays are all "mutable", unless you were to use something like [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), or if you were to pass in a `propertiesObject` to [Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) and made it not writable or something to that effect.

I am not familiar with `crossfilter`, but if the code you gave was correct, and `dataArray` is in fact an `Array` object, you should be able to make changes to it, given that you use correct JavaScript to do so.

For example, using the `Array` index accessor:

```
dataArray[1] = 'some new object';
```

**So to answer your question "is the `dataArray` I get here mutable or immutable?"**: It is mutable; just make sure you're trying to mutate it correctly.